# How to implement JDBC Template in web service java

Tags: java, database, spring, jdbc

I have written a web service in java. Its returning some values from database. Its working fin. But if I want to use JDBC Template I don't know how can I do that.

```
 public List<User> getUserDetails() {
        ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

    String dbUrl = "";
String dbClass = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
    String query = "select su.LDAP_DN, su.USERNAME, o.NAME as \"OFFICE\", o.OFFICE_CODE from OFFICE o, Users su where o.OFFICE_ID = su.OFFICE_ID ";
        String userName = "usr", password = "usr";
    try {
    Class.forName(dbClass);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl, userName, password);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) { 
         User user = new User();
             user.setUserName((rs.getString("USERNAME")));
         user.setLdap_DN((rs.getString("LDAP_DN")));
         user.setOfficeName((rs.getString("OFFICE")));
             user.setOfficeCode((rs.getString("OFFICE_CODE")));
           userList.add(user);
        }            
            con.close();            
        } 

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return userList; 


    }
```

I have the jdbc template object. I can implement that from main method from the same class. But how can I do that within my getUserDetails() method?
my main method

```
ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

        UsersImpl studentJDBCTemplate =  (UsersImpl)context.getBean("sixUserJdbcTemplate");

        List<SixUser> students = studentJDBCTemplate.getUserDetails();
        System.out.println(students.size());
```

Its working fine. But In my getUserDetails method how can I implement the jdbc template part.

Comment: Did you read through the [tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)?

Comment: yes I can execute that from main method. But In my web service implementation class there is no main method. I have only one getUserDatails method. I want to implement the beans calling and other parts inside my getUserDetails method. How can I do that?

Comment: Haven't you already implemented the JDBC part? You need to call this method from somewhere else to get your list

Comment: @cricket_007 hi there yes I have implemented the JDBC part. I can do that from the main method. But when I am creating the web service I am directly calling the method getUserDetails. If I write the code 
   the method can't find the beans.xml file. But if I run the same code by writting a main class it will work. What am I doing wrong? Is there any other alternative way to do the above three lines of code by any other way.

Comment: ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

        UsersImpl studentJDBCTemplate =  (UsersImpl)context.getBean("sixUserJdbcTemplate");

        List<SixUser> students = studentJDBCTemplate.getUserDetails();      System.out.println(students.size());

Comment: Hi there I made it work I have created another method from where I am calling the getUserDetails method and its working. What I want is that I want to do everything inside one method. But I think its not possible